# They are all K-verbs

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, language

**Find the missing verb.**

- G: Fold, Break, Pry
- D: Reduce, Vibrate, Rob
- B: Soak, Subtract, Thrash
- J: Sleep, Squeeze, ?

Subtle Hint:

> Another set:
>  J: Lose, Steam, Strike

Moderate Hint:

> "Fold" can be replaced by "Knead".
>  "Break" can be replaced by "Wake".
>  "Reduce" can be replaced by "Relieve".
>  "Vibrate" can be replaced by "Deduct".
>  "Rob" can be replaced by "Brush".
>  "Soak" can be replaced by "Conceive".
>  "Squeeze" can be replaced by "Weave".

Decisive Hint:

> If nouns are used instead of verbs:
>  G: Vigor, Meal, Height
>  D: Moon, Daughter, Mask
>  B: Fire, Horn, Grass
>  J: Luggage, Dibs, Saliva

Very Decisive Hint:

> Occlusives and aspiration.

Comment: Is there only one possible answer? Does the order of the words matter? Like Fold can be replaced by Knead, but can Break be replaced by Knead?

Comment: @DrXorile Order matters. There are multiple valid answers.

Comment: Is the spelling of occulsives important, or is it meant to be occlusives?

Comment: @DrXorile Shoot, you're right 